# KeyCloak Integration with Azure B2C UserName Mapping Issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak, azure-ad-b2c, keycloak-connect, aad-b2c

We’ve implemented a keycloak integration with Azure ADB2C as an identity provider. While mapping the user claims in keycloak from the b2c token, I’m seeing a blank for the ‘sub’ claim. Is there anything to modify in the B2C policy or the Keycloak mapping configuration settings. Please share your suggestions. I really appreciate your time in considering this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm issue Sub on B2C custom policy at RelyingParty as < SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" / > that will map to the user ObjectID.

[RelayParty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwwz4.png)
[TokenIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFVMi.png)

Is that issue that you are facing? The value of the Sub is blank? Maybe you just need add it on the TP for token issue. A difference on Keycloak and B2C (that I found in a customer) is about the name pattern, that B2C use ID and KC use string as name.